# 302 Redirection to manage S3 presigned URL same as bitbucket

Tags: amazon-s3, http-status-code-302, pre-signed-url

I was looking for better ways to implement s3 presigned URL. As if the page contains 50 object which are stored in private bucket. You need to hit 50 API calls to fetch presigned URL from frontend.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9wnoxly1wbnn5z/redirect.mov?dl=0

A video for the same can be found on above link, how bitbucket is handling this. Which seems pretty cool. As no API are hit and also URL provided from API is fixed & clean